# WordPress issue with inputs inside divs on ContactForm7

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So this is my first time using StackOverFlow and I looked for a solution for this problem everywhere, but none of them were helpful.

I am currently editing a page on a WordPress blog that has a form. So, to make it easier to handle, I separated the fields in 2 divs. Inside the divs, I have the inputs, but they are not aligned properly. I tried floating, using vertical align, etc etc and nothing worked.

[link](http://postimg.org/image/dysi0xt4h/) (I was not allowed to upload an image because of no reputation, sorry about this and for having no fiddle)

Here is the code of the divs:

```
<div class="ftdiv">
<div class="mvto">
<p><strong>Moving From</p></strong>
<hr>
<p>Address [text text-315]</p> 
<p>City [text text-315]</p>
<p>Postal Code [text text-315]</p>
<p>Apt. # [text text-315]</p>
<p>Province [text text-315]</p>
</div>

<div class="mvfrom">
<p><strong>Moving To</p></strong>
<hr>
<p>Address [text text-315]</p>
<p>City [text text-315]</p>
<p>Postal Code [text text-315]</p>
<p>Apt. # [text text-315]</p>
<p>Province [text text-315]</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.ftdiv {
    width: 100%;
}

.mvto {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.mvfrom {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}


#wpcf7-f289-p154-o1 input {
    width: 120px;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.smaller {
    font-size: 9px;
    font-style: italic;
}

#dropyear {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Please, if someone can help me, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: You can set `<label>`  to your text, and the give to that `<label>` a `width`

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/?html,css,output) of this, to show how your code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best practice create a `<label>` to text:

**CSS**

```
.ftdiv {
    width: 100%;
}

.mvto {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.mvfrom {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}


#wpcf7-f289-p154-o1 input {
    width: 120px;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.smaller {
    font-size: 9px;
    font-style: italic;
}

#dropyear {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

label{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 150px; // Adjust your needs
    text-align: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ftdiv">
<div class="mvto">
<p><strong>Moving From</p></strong>
<hr>
<p><label>Address</label> [text text-315]</p> 
<p><label>City</label> [text text-315]</p>
<p><label>Postal Code</label> [text text-315]</p>
<p><label>Apt.</label> # [text text-315]</p>
<p><label>Province</label> [text text-315]</p>
</div>

<div class="mvfrom">
<p><strong>Moving To</p></strong>
<hr>
<p><label>Address</label> [text text-315]</p>
<p><label>City</label> [text text-315]</p>
<p><label>Postal</label> Code [text text-315]</p>
<p><label>Apt.</label> # [text text-315]</p>
<p><label>Province</label> [text text-315]</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/hgh7ezu1/4/)**